# Intent extras not being preserved with startActivity

Tags: android, exception, android-intent

I am re-launching my application after my it crashes using `Thread.setDefaultUncauhtExceptionHandler()`.  I would like to pass an intent extra telling it that it just came back from the dead, however its not sticking.  Here is the `onCreate` of `LockedUpActivity`.

```
public class LockedUpActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler;

    private static final String RECOVERED = "recovered";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setDefaultHandler();

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra(RECOVERED, false)) {
            Log.i("LockedUp", "Back from the dead!");
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText("Back from the dead!");
        }
        else {
            Log.i("LockedUp", "Machiavelli in this..");
        }

    }

    public void goDownInFlames(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, GoingDownActivity.class));
    }

    private void setDefaultHandler() {
        defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockedUpActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(RECOVERED, true);
                startActivity(i);

                defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am setting the extra, however it is never "Back from the dead!"

Comment: Well, for one, I'd probably look at why your app is crashing so much first, before worrying about trying to handle the crashes...  Try removing all the Threads and loopers. Make sure your Activities are registered in the Manifest.

Comment: CaspNZ is right. This seems so pointless. You should always avoid your app to crash. Starting an activity there isn't a good idea anyway, your app crashed so acting further on that won't solve your problems. Take a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533932/how-to-make-the-force-close-window-display-friendly-app-name-instead-of-a-package/7536415#7536415).

Comment: This isn't an app that is actually crashing right now. We have proprietary crash reporting behavior that is going to be implemented in case of any uncaught exceptions. This is meant to gracefully bring the user back into the application to possibly collect information/resume operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an Application crashes or is 'forced stop', automatic garbage collection is done, variables are cleared, and so is the activity stack of the app. The extras won't remain there if the app crashes.