# How to modify style of android "force close" window?

Tags: android, styles, forceclose

Does anybody know how to modify the style of the "force close" window (*FC dialog*)?
I found a custom ROM with a nice picture at the dialog. At what place can I find the popup?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533932/how-to-make-the-force-close-window-display-friendly-app-name-instead-of-a-packag

Comment: I would recommend you to avoid the force close dialog rather than styling it :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to override uncaughtException,

```
@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
e.printStackTrace();    

   try {    

      // create your custom dialog
      displayErrorMessageToast();

      Thread.sleep(3500);    
   } catch (Exception e1) {    
      Log.e(TAG, "Error: ", e1);    
   } 
   finally 
   {    
      killApplicationProcess(e);    
   }
}
```

for more info:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/2iUH1Knz8gw

Comment: but this isn't posiable change all system fc dialog style in this way. I just need modify the fc dialog style.

Comment: if you llok at @Praful Bhatnagar 's answer, you can write your own UnCaughtException.java and set thread for your activity, like this :  Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnCaughtException(youractivity.this));

Comment: thanks very much, that answer could only modify ONE app fc dialog style. but i wanna change all system app fc dialog style.

Answer (score 0):

Try the approach given in this [blog](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/09/android-uncaughtexceptionhandler.html)

Copying here for quick reference:

Android `UncaughtExceptionHandler`

Implemented by objects that want to handle cases where a thread is being terminated by an uncaught exception. Upon such termination, the handler is notified of the terminating thread and causal exception. If there is no explicit handler set then the thread's group is the default handler.

Below i wrote the code user can send some bug report to Developer when application crashed.

Activity Code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
/**
*
* @author vijayakumar
*
*/
public class AndroidMADQAActivity extends Activity {
ViewFlipper flipper;
TextView textView = null;
Throwable throwable;
UnCaughtException un = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnCaughtException(AndroidMADQAActivity.this));
Integer[] items = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.e,R.drawable.d,R.drawable.c};
setContentView(R.layout.main);
textView.setText("Helloo Error Welcome");
}
}
```

**UnCaughtException.java**

```
package com.madqa;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.StatFs;
import android.util.Log;
/**
* {@link UncaughtExceptionHandler} send an e-mail with
* some debug information to the developer.
*
* @author VIJAYAKUMAR
*/
public class UnCaughtException implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
private static final String RECIPIENT = "iamvijayakumar@gmail.com";
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler previousHandler;
private Context context;
private static Context context1;
public UnCaughtException(Context ctx) {
context = ctx;
context1 = ctx;
}

private StatFs getStatFs() {
File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
return new StatFs(path.getPath());
}
private long getAvailableInternalMemorySize(StatFs stat) {
long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
return availableBlocks * blockSize;
}
private long getTotalInternalMemorySize(StatFs stat) {
long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
return totalBlocks * blockSize;
}
private void addInformation(StringBuilder message) {
message.append("Locale: ").append(Locale.getDefault()).append('\n');
try {
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo pi;
pi = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
message.append("Version: ").append(pi.versionName).append('\n');
message.append("Package: ").append(pi.packageName).append('\n');
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("CustomExceptionHandler", "Error", e);
message.append("Could not get Version information for ").append(
context.getPackageName());
}
message.append("Phone Model: ").append(android.os.Build.MODEL).append(
'\n');
message.append("Android Version: ").append(
android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE).append('\n');
message.append("Board: ").append(android.os.Build.BOARD).append('\n');
message.append("Brand: ").append(android.os.Build.BRAND).append('\n');
message.append("Device: ").append(android.os.Build.DEVICE).append('\n');
message.append("Host: ").append(android.os.Build.HOST).append('\n');
message.append("ID: ").append(android.os.Build.ID).append('\n');
message.append("Model: ").append(android.os.Build.MODEL).append('\n');
message.append("Product: ").append(android.os.Build.PRODUCT).append(
'\n');
message.append("Type: ").append(android.os.Build.TYPE).append('\n');
StatFs stat = getStatFs();
message.append("Total Internal memory: ").append(
getTotalInternalMemorySize(stat)).append('\n');
message.append("Available Internal memory: ").append(
getAvailableInternalMemorySize(stat)).append('\n');
}
public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
try {
StringBuilder report = new StringBuilder();
Date curDate = new Date();
report.append("Error Report collected on : ").append(curDate.toString()).append('\n').append('\n');
report.append("Informations :").append('\n');
addInformation(report);
report.append('\n').append('\n');
report.append("Stack:\n");
final Writer result = new StringWriter();
final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
report.append(result.toString());
printWriter.close();
report.append('\n');
report.append("**** End of current Report ***");
Log.e(UnCaughtException.class.getName(),
"Error while sendErrorMail"+report);
sendErrorMail(report);
} catch (Throwable ignore) {
Log.e(UnCaughtException.class.getName(),
"Error while sending error e-mail", ignore);
}
// previousHandler.uncaughtException(t, e);
}
/**
* This method for call alert dialog when application crashed!
* @author vijayakumar
*/
public void sendErrorMail(final StringBuilder errorContent) {
final AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
new Thread(){
@Override
public void run() {
Looper.prepare();
builder.setTitle("Sorry...!");
builder.create();
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
System.exit(0);
}
});
builder.setPositiveButton("Report", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String subject = "Your App crashed! Fix it!";
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder("Yoddle");
body.append('\n').append('\n');
body.append(errorContent).append('\n').append('\n');
// sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { RECIPIENT });
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body.toString());
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
// context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Error Report"));
context1.startActivity(sendIntent);
System.exit(0);
}
});
builder.setMessage("Unfortunately,This application has stopped");
builder.show();
Looper.loop();
}
}.start();
}
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i still wanna change the system fc dialog style. the way you given work fine for a app. I want system level change. such as:may be dalvik catch a exception, it call fc dialog .I need change the dialog style.